# Special permissions on a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I need to grant permission on a group where they only can edit the items that the list currently has and forbid them to change the list view or adding/deleting items. I've been looking at list configuration, but it seems that the options are too limited. I also looked at Item Level Permission Setting but it is not what I need, since I will create all the items. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a `custom permission level` based on your requirement as the following

- At the Site Collection > Go to Site Settings > Site permissions > from the above ribbon  Permission Level .

[image]

- Click Add Permission Level with your required permission (Edit Items)

[image]

- Now create your group with this new custom Permission Level.
- Add the users to this group > Add this group to your List Permission